# Adding a node after executing remove node state in Service Fabric Cluster

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm experiencing a very weird issue.

I had a Service Fabric cluster of 5 nodes and all of them are part of a single VM Scale Set. There was an issue with one of the node, so I removed it from the Explorer by clicking on 'Remove node state'. That removed the node from the cluster.

Now, my cluster has only 4 nodes.

However, I added another node to the VM Scaleset using ARM Template.

I would like to add this node to the service fabric cluster and I'm not able to do it.

When I execute the powershell command ' Get-ServiceFabricClusterManifest', it shows all the nodes under 'Vote' node.

```
<Infrastructure>
   <PaaS>
     <Roles>
       <Role RoleName="vmnode" NodeTypeRef="vmnode" RoleNodeCount="5" />
     </Roles>
     <Votes>
       <Vote NodeName="_vmnode_0" IPAddressOrFQDN="10.1.10.9" Port="1025" />
       <Vote NodeName="_vmnode_1" IPAddressOrFQDN="10.1.10.10" Port="1025" />
       <Vote NodeName="_vmnode_2" IPAddressOrFQDN="10.1.10.11" Port="1025" />
       <Vote NodeName="_vmnode_3" IPAddressOrFQDN="10.1.10.12" Port="1025" />
       <Vote NodeName="_vmnode_4" IPAddressOrFQDN="10.1.10.13" Port="1025" />
     </Votes>
   </PaaS>
 </Infrastructure>
```

But when I execute Get-ServiceFabricNode, it only shows the 4 nodes. It doesn't show the other node that exists in the VMScaleSet.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ServiceFabricNode


NodeName        : _vmnode_1
NodeId          : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NodeInstanceId  : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NodeType        : vmnode
NodeStatus      : Up
NodeUpTime      : 11:53:19
HealthState     : Ok
CodeVersion     : 5.6.205.9494
ConfigVersion   : 4
IsSeedNode      : True
IpAddressOrFQDN : 10.1.10.10
FaultDomain     : fd:/1
UpgradeDomain   : 1
IsStopped       : False

NodeName        : _vmnode_2
NodeId          : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NodeInstanceId  : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NodeType        : vmnode
NodeStatus      : Up
NodeUpTime      : 18:38:58
HealthState     : Ok
CodeVersion     : 5.6.205.9494
ConfigVersion   : 4
IsSeedNode      : True
IpAddressOrFQDN : 10.1.10.11
FaultDomain     : fd:/2
UpgradeDomain   : 2
IsStopped       : False

NodeName        : _vmnode_3
NodeId          : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NodeInstanceId  : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NodeType        : vmnode
NodeStatus      : Up
NodeUpTime      : 18:24:21
HealthState     : Ok
CodeVersion     : 5.6.205.9494
ConfigVersion   : 4
IsSeedNode      : True
IpAddressOrFQDN : 10.1.10.12
FaultDomain     : fd:/3
UpgradeDomain   : 3
IsStopped       : False

NodeName        : _vmnode_4
NodeId          : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NodeInstanceId  : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NodeType        : vmnode
NodeStatus      : Up
NodeUpTime      : 18:11:00
HealthState     : Ok
CodeVersion     : 5.6.205.9494
ConfigVersion   : 4
IsSeedNode      : True
IpAddressOrFQDN : 10.1.10.13
FaultDomain     : fd:/4
UpgradeDomain   : 4
IsStopped       : False
```

What am I missing? I need to be able to add the extra node to the cluster but I can't figure out how to add more nodes to the cluster!

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: I just removed a node state, and after 5-10 mins a new node was automatically added to the cluster by Service Fabric to meet it's target size.